# ffmpeg: how to convert to DNxHR in Windows 10?

Tags: ffmpeg, codec

I have installed ffmpeg version `3.2.2` from the ffmpeg.org download page.

When I enter `ffmpeg formats`, I see **dnxhd** but not **dnxhr**.  What do I need to do to be able to manipulate **dnxhr**?

I have downloaded and installed [Avid Codecs LE 2.7.3](http://avid.force.com/pkb/articles/en_US/download/Avid-QuickTime-Codecs-LE) as well but that didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a single decoder/encoder which reads/converts to both DNxHD and DNxHR.

You have to set the correct profile switch. Available options are

```
 dnxhd                        E..V....
 dnxhr_444                    E..V....
 dnxhr_hqx                    E..V....
 dnxhr_hq                     E..V....
 dnxhr_sq                     E..V....
 dnxhr_lb                     E..V....
```

Basic minimal syntax would be

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -c:v dnxhd -profile:v dnxhr_hq out.mov
```

---

The Avid codecs package has no interaction with ffmpeg.

**[19-1-2017]** At this time, the encoder does not support 444 or HQX profiles.

**[4-2-2017]** Now, it does.

Comment: What command did you use to get a list of supported profiles?

Comment: `ffmpeg -h encoder=dnxhd`